# possible? Win32 fully safe execution

Tags: c++, security, winapi, win32-process

please, dont propose   analysing of machine code.

? is there  way to load application with   disallow to use any API,  disallow to use of any hacking system methods ???

i want to run third-party applications writed in c++ with limitation to computing only

Comment: *disallow to use of any hacking system methods* Yeah, all those `BOOL HackSystem(HWHATTOHACK hWhatToHack)` which Microsoft added that have no legitimate purpose whatsoever.

Comment: What's with the downvotes? It's not a bad question...

Comment: @Mehrdad The question is almost incomprehensible, doesn't show any research effort, or even basic insight on the asker's part. It violates everything that is stackoverflow. And incidentally marks it as such by placing questionmarks at random.

Comment: @IInspectable: I mean I agree it's poorly *written*, but the question itself is actually a decent one -- for example, if you've never heard of the correct terms (e.g. "sandboxing"), I imagine it's pretty hard to know what to search for in the first place. So I'm not surprised at the lack of a displayed research effort either. It would be better if people didn't downvote it into oblivion when the underlying question is fine...

Comment: "Limitation to computing only." Kind of makes for a useless program if it can't do any input or output.

Comment: input/output will be provided by some Main Apllication with using WriteProcessMemory/ReadProcessMemory

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Create a limited-rights user account and run the application in that account.

In particular, do not give that user the "debug" privilege (`SeDebugPrivilege`). That block `ReadProcessMemory` outright.